# Path to Manifolds from HS Algebra and Calculus?

Tags: manifolds, self-learning, smooth-manifolds, general-relativity, complex-manifolds

Is there a coherent path from high school algebra and beginning calculus to fully understanding the manifolds? In other words, can one self-study towards manifolds, only assuming a very modest mathematics background?

I understand that a lot of books on manifolds has been introduced, and although I had a course in topology (without any analysis), It's really hard for me to understand the subject.

So, I was just wondering if there could be a path from scratch that I can follow and also brush up on topology which I guess should be on the path.

Comment: I mean, depends on what you want to do with manifolds. Most people don't just learn manifolds for the sake of learning manifolds.

Comment: I'm mostly interesting in them because of general relativity. I know there are books on GR and also am reading them, but they either talk about them shortly without any rigorous mathematics or they go really deep where I can't really understand them and because of these, I want to study them from scratch.

Comment: If that's your goal, it won't be a short path. You'll need a proper introduction to abstract algebra, complex and functional analysis.

Comment: Manifolds aren't the hard part of GR. It's what is done with them that is.

Comment: I'm willing to do that and that's not a real problem, my problem is the lack of coherent path. It'd be great if you could show me a path with books.

Comment: Start with Rudin's Analysis, move to D&F's algebra, followed by A&M's Commutative Algebra, then Rudin's Functional Analysis. That's probably the shortest route, but that's tough. I would recommend around 2~3 years to finish the material.

Comment: How about Spivak's _Calcula on Manifolds_, which is serious but accessible?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your recommendations but what books on manifolds should I start with then?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion I don't think you would need commutative algebra or functional analysis to understand (at least the basics of) manifolds.

Maybe something like

1. Linear algebra (vector spaces and linear maps abstracly) - very important
2. Multivariable calculus/analysis - also very important
3. Real analysis & topology
4. Maybe a bit of abstract algebra helps (groups, rings, modules, etc.)

But I don't know what's a good order to do them. I had to keep going back to things I already read to understand them in a new way.

There are a lot of linear algebra books, it's important to learn about abstract vector spaces and linear maps. I heard good things about Axler - Linear algebra done right. I learned from Hoffman & Kunze.

Spivak - "Calculus on manifolds" is a very good multivariable calculus book that I learned from.

Rudin - "Principles of mathematical analysis", the first several chapters is just generally useful analysis and topology to have.

Then I first read Tu - "Intro to smooth manifolds", and that was good to learn from. Or Sean Carroll's GR book looks good.

Of course there are many alternative books, but I think these areas are the needed background.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer seems more related or at least it reaches manifolds sooner. But I do have a question. Why would I even need functional analysis or commutative algebra to study manifolds even in a more advanced level? How they are used?

Comment: Maybe that comment was me being nice. I don't really know what the association is. Functional analysis is good for infinite dimensional analysis and PDE's, which I guess come up later in differential geometry, and commutative algebra has some place close to algebraic geometry. But I think these subjects are extended from, or adjacent to, knowledge of manifolds. I can say that I deal with manifolds very much and know very little functional analysis and almost no commutative algebra. It's good for "culture" to know more but it would probably slow you down if you're just trying to understand GR.

Comment: @MohammadNourbakhsh As a graduate student working in GR theory, I haven't yet had occasion to use either functional analysis or commutative algebra in my work; certainly, neither is necessary to understand the core features of GR. Functional analysis is probably useful to understanding Einstein's equation as a system of PDE's, say in questions related to the Cosmic Censorship Conjecture(s). As far as applications in physics goes, though, functional analysis is much more directly useful to understanding QM than GR.

Comment: @Keshav Thanks a lot. I agree with you because my focus is on GR so as you said it'd probably just slow me down.

Comment: @jawheele Thanks a lot. So as a graduate student working on GR, what are your suggestions to my question? It'd really help me.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the general path that Kreshav has laid out. Linear algebra is definitely the place to start, and it's a good topic in which to first get familiar with formal proofs in practice. I liked Serge Lang's Linear Algebra. It's then crucial to know multivariable calculus, preferably from an analysis perspective. You can pick up much of what you absolutely need about topology from a good intro analysis text (Rudin is popular). You'd then have the bare-bones tools necessary to approaching manifolds, and for doing so with an eye towards GR, the hands-down best text (in my opinion) is O'Neill's Semi-Riemannian Geometry. A text on Semi-Riemannian geometry is necessary so that one can separate results specific to Riemannian geometry (typically what is focused on in pure math contexts) from the Lorentzian case. With the mathematical footing solid, one might then look at a physics source like Wald to develop your understanding of the physical ideas, motivations, and history.

A lot of details fall by the wayside on that most direct path, in particular various results in point-set topology and a study of algebraic structures that familiarizes you with constructions like quotients and tensor products. What's more, O'Neill doesn't develop integration on manifolds (crucial for many physics discussions, such as an action approach), so one should look to an alternative text for that, perhaps Lee's smooth manifolds.

All that being said, many physicists get by without a single course in proof-based mathematics and manage to utilize GR sufficiently for their purposes all the same. With that in mind, you might do well enough by understanding multivariable calculus and vector spaces from a more computational perspective and starting with a text like Wald. Ultimately, the level of rigor you care to indulge in is up to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I just have a question. What about topology? because I looked at O'Neill's and it starts the definition of the manifolds using a Hausdorff space which I couldn't find a definition of in Rudin's.

Actually I've read some of the books on GR from a physicist's point of view. Although they're understandable but I feel a void because of their level of rigor which they don't explain too deep. Like you said most of the physicists get by without them, but I guess if you want to develop the theory you should know how it's structured and constructed deeply.

Comment: @MohammadNourbakhsh There are a couple of useful topological definitions assumed in O'Neill (such as Hausdorff), but if you have some minimal intuition of topological spaces (or at least metric spaces) from a text like Rudin, you'd probably do best just finding those definitions on wikipedia as you encounter them. To get a feel for the Hausdorff condition, you might refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_axiom. Another topological concept that comes up is second countable, but O'Neill discusses this. A proof of the related result of existence of partitions of unity is given by Lee.

Comment: @MohammadNourbakhsh That being said, if you want to understand manifolds beyond what's directly useful to GR, there's a lot more topology one might explore. In particular, cohomology groups are important features of topological spaces that have an interesting relationship with a manifold's smooth structure. A good text on this subject is Bott and Tu, but one should probably first go through the first couple of chapters of Hatcher to familiarize oneself with algebraic topology at large. Of course, it is more essential to this study that you are familiar with the basic algebraic structures.